# Redirecting to app store if the URL scheme is called

Tags: iphone, url, redirect, app-store

I know that I can call up an app in the iPhone safari by calling the app's URL scheme.
But can I get any feedback if the app I wanted to open with is not present?
Cause I am thinking to redirecting the user to app store directly when the URL e.g.(fb://) is called and when no response. I can see safari prompt me and tell me that it can not go to the URL, but is there any way that I can capture the response?

Answer (score 0):

Once Safari starts there is no return value. Your app is terminated or backgrounded.

Comment: Thanks progrmr. Sorry that I didn't make myself clear. I am having in mind a mobile web and not a native app. If I have a link on the mobile web with the link to like fb:// , and the Facebook app is not present in the iPhone, can I recognize that and redirect to the Facebook app's app store link?